# Stopping a systemd service when a user logs in to the GUI

Tags: systemd, login

Is it possible to stop a systemd service when a user logs in to a GUI?  I'm guessing it would require some sort of custom target, or perhaps use [logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/)? If so, then how can I do this?

If that's too vague and more context is needed: I have a computer lab running Ubuntu that I would like to use as a Blender renderfarm.  I would like to utilize unused computers as render slaves.  I have a service that starts the rendering slave, but I'd like the service to stop if someone logs in to the GUI to use the computer so it isn't hogging the CPU in the background rendering.

Comment: job schedulers such as `condor` appear to use a talks-to-the-X11 server thing to see if someone is local: https://lists.cs.wisc.edu/archive/htcondor-users/2015-August/msg00098.shtml

Comment: To a zeroth approximation, can't you run your blender with a good `nice` value?

Comment: systemd has a [`Conflicts` dependency](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=) that might be useful, but I don't know if you can conflict with a session. (Also, I assume you want blender to resume when the user logs out?)

Comment: resuming would be bonus, but not required.  Stopping it IS required.