# /etc/profile.d/ script: Interactive authentication required

Tags: shell-script, login, group

I have a [service that I want to stop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409100/stopping-a-systemd-service-when-a-user-logs-in-to-the-gui) when a user logs in the a workstation.

I've tried putting a bash script in `/etc/profile.d/`, and it runs when a user logs in, however, an error message pops up saying "interactive authentication required" to stop the service.

The user may not have root privileges.  Is there a way to get scripts in /etc/profile.d to run with he privileges it needs to run this script, without requiring the logging in user to provide them?

Here's the script:

```
~$ cat /etc/profile.d/stop-netrender-slave.sh 
#!/bin/bash
systemctl stop netrender-slave
```

EDIT:

Is it possible to run the service as a particular group, so that a user who is a member of that group has permissions to stop the service?

Comment: What's the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo`. It allows a non root user to run commands as `root`. You can configure it (with the flag `NOPASSWD`) so that certain users can run certain commands without having to enter a password.